Find the present value of a perpetuity due whose annual payments are \$2, \$2, \$4, \$2, \$2, \$6, \$2, \$2, \$8,...
Problem:
Find the present value of a perpetuity due whose annual payments are \$2, \$2, \$4, \$2, \$2, \$6, \$2, \$2, \$8, .... The annual effective interest rate is 2%.
I'm thinking of breaking it into a constant perpetuity that pays \$2 every year, and an increasing perpetuity that increases by \$2 every 3 years, with the first payment being \$4. Well, the first part is easy to compute, as it is just $2\left(\dfrac{1.02}{0.02}\right)$ but how should I go about calculating the second part?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

The schedule of payments is not clear.  And what does $2%$ mean here?  A constant effective interest rate should mean a constant coupon, right?  Or did you mean to say that the riskless rate was $2%$?

@lulu 2% refers to the compound interest rate. Since it's annual effective, it's compounding once every year at 2%

Why is this question being downvoted/closed? It literally comes from the textbook

Let $~v = \dfrac{1}{1.02}.$
This answer assumes that the first payment starts immediately, instead of 1 year from now.  If this is not the case, simply multiply my overall answer by $~v.$

The payments can be represented as

$2~$ every year. 
Assuming that the payments start immediately, the present value is 
$2(1 + v + v^2 + \cdots) = \dfrac{2}{1-v}.$

An additional payment of :

$2~$ at the end of year $~2.~$

$4~$ at the end of year $~5.~$

$6~$ at the end of year $~8.~$

$\cdots$




So, the problem reduces to computing the present value of the additional payments, which may be expressed as
$$\frac{2}{v} \times [ ~1v^3 + 2v^6 + 3v^9 + 4v^{12} + \cdots ~]. \tag1 $$
In order to compute the expression in (1) above, you need the formula that for $~|x| < 1,~$ that
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty nx^n = \frac{x}{(1 - x)^2}. \tag2 $$
Setting $~x = v^3,~$ and applying the formula in (2) above to the expression in (1) above, the expression in (1) above equals
$$\frac{2}{v} \times \frac{v^3}{(1 - v^3)^2}. \tag3 $$
Combining the expression in (3) above, with the results of the first bullet point, at the start of my answer, the overall present value is
$$\frac{2}{1-v} + \left[ ~\frac{2}{v} \times \frac{v^3}{(1 - v^3)^2} ~\right]. \tag4 $$
As mentioned at the start of my answer, for the alternate assumption that the payments start one year from now, rather than immediately, simply multiply the entire expression in (4) above by $~v.$

Ok that's genius, I didn't know about the (2) formula. And yes since this is a perpetuity due, the payments start immediately.
